# verilog module renaming using precompiler

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga

I want to name a module using a `define directive

It seems to work if I use a macro like :

```
`define module_rename(NAME,TAG) ``NAME``TAG

module `module_rename(foo,_A) (...);
```

but it fails (in quartus) if I do the following :

```
`define NAME foo
`define TAG _A

module `NAME`TAG (...);
```

Syntax Error near_A missing";"

Any idea what is wrong ?

Tx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SystemVerilog token pasting operator ``` `` ``` is only allowed in the body of a `` `define `` text macro, and that is the only place you can join text together to form a single identifier. The second example you wrote is seen as illegal syntax.

```
module foo _A;
```